# Help with xbox gamepad and Wine

Tags: wine

I installed my xbox gamepad with "xboxdrv_0.8.2-1_amd64.deb" and the controller works just fine with Linux games such as Open Arena. The difficulty I am haveing is when I play DOOM64 EX in Wine, my gamepad is not detected. DOOM 64 EX detects my gamepad in Windows, so its not my version of DOOM. I hope some one could point me in the right direction to get this to work.

Comment: Wine has well known issues with communicating with USB devices.

Comment: My answer [for this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140617/how-do-i-use-a-gamepad/225484#225484) might be useful for you as I discuss a very useful tool called `qjoypad`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Doom 64 Ex is doing, but a general problem withe Xbox360 gamepads and Windows is that there are two APIs for input in Window, Xinput and DirectInput. Wine only emulates the later, older API, and doesn't handle Xinput at all. Some modern games however require Xinput.

There is a workaround via a Xbox360 controller emulation DLL (the same you would use to make an old pre-Xinput gamepad work with modern games in Windows). This thread describes it:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/xboxdrv/wgY0sp-drD8

Comment: Thats not any help. Why isn’t there a way to get this to work? I would think it it would be in the best interest of Wine to support game controllers. There has to be a way to tell wine to look at my gamepad.

Comment: If Doom64Ex requires Xinput then there is no way to use your gamepad directly, you have to the .dll hack.