# Gamepad Controller issues on Ubuntu 12.04+

Tags: games, xbox-360

For whatever reason I can never get any of my controllers to work properly on Ubuntu. The main one I want to get working is the Xbox 360 controller (wired, not wireless). It detects the L and R triggers as axis which causes serious issues in a majority of games. I press any of the triggers and it suddenly makes the game unplayable. A similar issue occurs with the PS3 Controller.

I thought that if I bought a PC game controller it would fix my issue...but man was I wrong. Is there some type of secret method to getting this to work...I'm so irritated!!!

Even configuring inputs for emulators is a pain. If I press say "A" once it shoots the entire list down with Button 1.

Comment: The XBox 360 controller's triggers are analog though, not digital. So they should be read as such.

Comment: You could try using Qjoypad or something similar, as that has allowed me to use gamepads in dosbox and native games, etc, where either there was a problem, or the game itself did not support any sort of gamepad. See the [useful answers for this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140617/how-do-i-use-a-gamepad)

Comment: I've used Qjoypad and various apps before and none seem to fix this issue. The issue seems to be that the Axis input gets "stuck" making the computer think that it's not being released. Similar things happen with other buttons. Pressing A, B, Y, X once sends the computer multiple signals for each. Resulting in multiple button presses.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix your problems is to use `xboxdrv`:

- http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/

It's a userspace driver for the Xbox360 controller that allows you to configure and remap your controller, so that triggers are handled as buttons instead of axis and things like that, the `--trigger-as-button` option is what you want.

Comment: My controller is being detected as a "logic3"  0e6f:0401 thus isn't being picked up by xboxdrv (and might be my issue all together). It's a gamestop Xbox 360 wired controller. I'm sure it would work if I somehow added the ID to xboxdrv..any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: `xboxdrv --device-by-id 0e6f:0401 --type xbox360`

Comment: @Matthew That's odd, I have a Gamestop Xbox360 wired controller and it's detected as an Xbox controller perfectly fine. I don't see why yours would be any different.

Comment: To get the right device-by-id for that command you want to run `lsusb` and look for `microsoft xbox 360 controller`