# Mapping playstation controller to keys

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu

Title might not be right, just no idea what to type.

I am in possession of a DualShock 3 (A.k.a playstation 3 controller) and a wire to my lubuntu 12.04 notebook. Bluetooth does not work on this.
I want to play a game with not so many controls, Cave Story + to be precise, using this controller. After toying around in qtsixa and different things I've found scattered across the web I've given up, I've tried re-mapping the buttons without any form of signs why it doesn't work.

Oh, and the buttons that I want to bind (On the keyboard) are Up-, Down-, Left- and right arrows, A,S, Z, X Q, W (I think that's all.)

If you need more information just ask!

Comment: Try `qjoypad`: my article [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140617/how-do-i-use-a-gamepad) might be useful, as it isn't in the repositories.

Comment: How exactly do I launch the game? There is no way to change the in-game key bindings and I am also not sure if I can edit the whole qjoypad, since not all of it is shown on the window.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `sudo apt-get install joy2key` and read the documentation for it.