# Alternative to QJoyPad

Tags: software-recommendation, joystick

I'd like to know if there is any alternative to [QJoyPad](http://qjoypad.sourceforge.net/), I've tried to install it, but it's only available from the source and is not possible to compile it, because of some errors. Anyway, you can't install it from a deb package, because it was packed into deb for the last time in 2004-09-19 according to its official web-page in Source Forge.

So I'm here asking for a software recomendation or an alternative to QJoyPad.

What's QJoyPad:

> A QT-Based program that takes input from joystick/gamepad devices and produces keyboard or mouse activity in XWindows. Great for games with no or mediocre joystick support as well as for emulation. Easy to set up. Supports any number of devices.
> From: [Source Forge](http://qjoypad.sourceforge.net/)

### Edit:

The error message is the following:

```
Error: you will need libxtst to compile this program
```

And this compiler (I think) ins't available in the repository, just it's `libxtst-doc`.

Comment: I compiled `Qjoypad` fine recently: what were the error messages? You may have needed the QT libraries (`sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev`):see [here for more information](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140617/how-do-i-use-a-gamepad/225484#225484). An alternative is `joy2key` which is in the repositories, but may be trickier to set up.

Comment: I think you just need to run `sudo apt-get install libxtst6 libxtst-dev`. That should sort out the problem. Both of these files are in the repositories for the last 6 Ubuntu versions, so you should be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clear alternatives are `joy2key`, which is available in the repositories, and `rejoystick`, which I discuss further below.

1) **Fixing compilation problems**

However, I believe it is possible to sort out your compilation problems with `qjoypad` now that you have posted the error messages. It is worth trying to get it compiled as you may find the QT interface much easier to use than the command-line one of `joy2key`.

Your error message suggests that you need [libxtst6](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libxtst6%20&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) and [libxtst-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libxtst-dev), which have been in the repositories for the last 6 Ubuntu releases. So please run

```
sudo apt-get install libxtst6 libxtst-dev
```

If you have any further errors you may need to ensure that you have the QT development libraries installed, as they are necessary for building the interface.

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
```

More information is detailed in my [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140617/how-do-i-use-a-gamepad/225484#225484), which explains how to compile `qjoypad` and then set up your joystick.

---

2) **Alternatives**

a) joy2key

In the package description, it is noted that

> joy2key allows one to choose keyboard events for joystick axes and buttons,
>    so that a joystick or gamepad can be used with an application that doesn't
>    have native joystick support.

Unfortunately, there is no gui (or none that I know of) that yet exists for `joy2key`, so an essential read is `man joy2key` and, for example, [this and other threads](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=646564&highlight=joy2key) on Ubuntuforums, which go into detail as to how to set it up, although it can be tricky to get it right.

Even though you can save your `joy2key` configuration in `.joy2keyrc`; it is difficult to share configurations, as the joystick needs calibrating properly on your machine. However, you may be able to find some layouts for your joystick/gamepad on other forums if you face problems setting your own up.

b) Rejoystick

If you have problems with `joy2key`, [rejoystick](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rejoystick/?source=navbar) would probably be better, as it has a gui (see screenshot) that you use to setup your joypad (see screenshot). You can install the deb from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rejoystick/files/latest/download?source=files). You connect your joypad, launch the settings gui by entering `rejoystick` in terminal, and then you enter your settings and click ok to save the profile  to `~/.rejoystickrc`. Then you just run `rejoystick -d` before you launch your game; enter `killall -s SIGKILL rejoystick` to clear the current bindings in effect. It does seem to work, but I'm not sure if you can have different profiles like you can with `qjoypad`.

[image]

In short, I highly recommend trying the solutions given further above to solve the compiling problems with `qjoypad`, as `joy2key` can be a pain to get set up correctly, although `rejoystick` is much simpler and may be useful.

Comment: Thanks Mik, with your help I could compile the qjoypad and now I can play Minecraft with my joypad.

Comment: @Zignd Ah, that's good news, glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 7):

Besides the software that Mik mentioned in his answer, I would also recommend that you check out the program AntiMicro. I started developing it as a replacement for QJoyPad but there are some features that AntiMicro has that QJoyPad lacks. Some of the more noteworthy features are that multiple keys can be assigned to one controller button (Shift+Tab), macros allow for conditional button presses, set integration for changing button configurations on the fly, and the program uses a tray icon that works properly under Unity.

The project is hosted on GitHub and the latest deb files can be found at my website.

https://github.com/Ryochan7/antimicro

http://www.ryochan7.com/files/projects/antimicro/antimicro_0.7-1_amd64.deb

Comment: Thanks for developing this software! I got tired of hacking patches together to get `qjoypad` to behave, nice to see a newer rewrite.

Comment: Hey that's cool. Maybe I wouldn't have invested as much time in fixing QJoyPad if I would've seen this earlier. Here is my QJoyPad fork anyway: https://github.com/panzi/qjoypad (Fixes memory leaks, adds a feature to invoke mouse clicks via an axis, uses cmake, some refactorings etc.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to try other DEB or APT:

search for qjoypad at http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/

the DEB there install fine without need to compile!