# How to configure Qjoypad?

Tags: games, install-from-source, gamepad

I followed the steps on [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140617/how-do-i-use-a-gamepad?lq=1) but when I run `make` it gives me this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: keycode.o: undefined reference to symbol 'XKeycodeToKeysym'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'XKeycodeToKeysym' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: could not read symbols: Invalid operation collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`

Comment: Have you got all the build dependencies installed, e.g `libx11-dev`, etc.

Comment: I've just compiled successfully on Xubuntu 12.04; my instructions seem to be fine. Check again whether you have all the build dependencies installed.

Comment: yup, I've got them all. I tried again, and it said the same thing, I also noticed that it was saying this, too: `error.h:8:13: warning: 'void error(QString, QString)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]`

Answer (score 4):

This is an Ubuntu thing, works fine without it in Debian Stable. So might effect Mint too.

Add `-lX11` in the Makefile to the LIBS line under the LFLAGS line so it should look like this when your done.

For 64bit:

LIBS = $(SUBLIBS)  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lXtst -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread -lX11

For 32bit:

LIBS = $(SUBLIBS)  -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lXtst -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread -lX11

They changed the way they compiled to be more exact and broke code from what I get. This worked fine with the exact error on 64bit Ubuntu thanks to someone on the web I found. Every time you run the ./config or ./configure it will remake the Makefile and you have to edit it again.

The Keyboard is dead, Long live the Keyboard. :P

Comment: Note: if you are following the [Arc Synthesis OpenGL tutorial](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/), you might get the error described in the original question on Ubuntu.  To fix it, just open the target makefile (such as `Tut 01 Main.make`), go down to the `LIBS` section under `debug` and `release`, and add `-lX11`.  That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a problem with your X11 library.

Just reinstall X11 library

`sudo apt-get autoremove libx11-6`

and then

`sudo apt-get install libx11-6`

Comment: I did that, and then `make` and then this happened `usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lXtst -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld: keycode.o: undefined reference to symbol 'XKeycodeToKeysym'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'XKeycodeToKeysym' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: could not read symbols: Invalid operation collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [qjoypad] Error 1`

Comment: Did that solve your problem?

Comment: No, it did not.

Comment: Wasn't trying to sound rude there, I had to fulfill the 15 character minimum

Comment: No probs... I updated the answer now, can you please try that?

Comment: just did, still to no success :(

Comment: `error.h:21:13: warning: ‘void debug_mesg(...)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]  
/usr/bin/ld: keycode.o: undefined reference to symbol 'XKeycodeToKeysym'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: could not read symbols: Invalid operation`

Comment: There will be a file called config.log. Can you please share that? And are you sure /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 file exists?

Comment: I don't have the /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 file, and I don't have the config.log one either.

Comment: Can you try this command? `ldconfig -p | grep -in x11`

Comment: I found it, actually. I uninstalled `libx11-dev` and reinstalled it. It exists

Comment: Cool. Try the same configure and make drill, as mentioned above

Comment: It's still saying the same things

Comment: Would you mind showing me, each and every command you execute in the process of installing, along with the output?

Comment: Sure, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1vDYTutJLxo

Comment: Can you please try to reinstall libx11 as shown in the answer?

Comment: Sure thing. I just need to finish with software updates