# How to use a Dualshock 2 controller with Ubuntu?

Tags: gamepad

How can I use a Playstation 2 Dualshock 2 controller on Linux? I have an adapter, so it is UUSB connected to my computer. I just want to be able to map the buttons on the controller to keys so I can use it in tf2.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and add the output of `lsusb`? The USB ID of a device usually helps finding out if a device is detected and supported.

Comment: If it's just about mapping buttons, then answers to these questions should be useful: http://askubuntu.com/q/140617/40581 http://askubuntu.com/q/32031/40581

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about that specific controller but I have used [jstest-gtk](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/jstest-gtk/) for other ones.